# How can I use geolocation watchPosition in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, geolocation

i want to use the geolocation.watchPosition in angular js in order to find my new location every 3minutes something like gps tracker. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If you just want to get the position every third minute you might as well use `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. `Geolocation.watchPosition()` is used to automatically get updates  each time the position of the device changes.

Comment: i think its better to get positions every time that the device's position changed.. So i think i have to use geolocation.watchPosition(). Do you know how i can use it in angular?

Comment: You wrote in your question that you wanted to find the location every third minute. You want to get the position every time the device's position changes instead? Have you tried anything at all yet? Can you show any code?

Comment: yes finally its better to take location every time that device's location changed. i have wrote this in a controller..  <code>                   function geo_success(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(lat);
      console.log(lng);
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.lat = lat;
        $scope.lng = lng;
 });    function geo_error(error){
    console.log ("gps lost");
  }


  var watchID = $window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success,geo_error, {enableHighAccuracy: true });

Answer (score 0):

```
appControllers.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$routeParams', '$http','$window','$interval',
function geo_success(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lng = position.coords.longitude;
console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
$scope.$apply(function(){
$scope.lat = lat;
$scope.lng = lng;
});
$scope.latlng = function(){
$http.post('/profile', {
latitude: $scope.lat,
longitude: $scope.lng
})
.success(function(user){
// No error: authentication OK
$rootScope.message = 'Lat/Lng send ok!';
})
.error(function(){
// Error: authentication failed
$rootScope.message = 'Lat/Lng dont send';
});
};
}
function geo_error(error){
console.log ("gps lost");
}
var watchID = $window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success,geo_error,     {enableHighAccuracy: true });
}]);

this i have write
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help.

```
angular.module("GeoService",[]).
factory('GeoLocation',['$rootScope', '$window', '$q', '$resource', function($rootScope, $window, $q, $resource){
    var _geoCapable = false,
        _deferred = $q.defer(),
        _errorMsg = null;
        //Geolocation options
        _option = {
                enableHighAccuracy:true,
                timeout: 5000,
                maximumAge: 0,
                desiredAccuracy: 0,
                frequency: 1         
            };

    if($window.navigator && $window.navigator.geolocation){
        _geoCapable = true;
    }

    if(!_geoCapable){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('geo:error', 'Geolocation not supported');
    }

    //Geolocation function onSucces
    _onSucces = function (position) {
                _deferred.resolve(position);               
            };

    //Geolocation function onFail
    _onFail =  function (error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    _errorMsg = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                    break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    _errorMsg = "Location information is unavailable."
                    break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                    _errorMsg = "The request to get user location timed out."
                    break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    _errorMsg = "An unknown error occurred."
                    break;
                };
                $rootScope.$broadcast('geo:error', _errorMsg);
                _deferred.reject(_errorMsg);
            };

    //Service API
    var _locationService = {
        //getPosition() function:
        getLocation: function(){
            if(!_geoCapable){
                return _deferred.reject();
            };
            $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(_onSucces,_onFail,_option);
            return _deferred.promise;
        },

        //watchPosition() function:
        watchPosition: function(){
            if(!_geoCapable){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('geo:error','Geolocation not supported');                
            };
            $window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('geo:positionUpdate', position);
            }, _onFail);
        }
    };
    return _locationService;
}]);
```